# php --version bash: php: command not found

Tags: php, magento2, git-bash

I was looking for switch from magento default mode to developer mode typing

> deploy:mode:set developer

But my bash gave me that error. How can i fix it? I already tried with

> $ find / -name php -type f,

but the bash gave me

> find: failed to read file names from file system at or below ‘/’: No
>   such file or directory

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Also try `locate php` on linux

Comment: i'm using windows

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't have PHP on your PATH.

Try:

```
which php
```

On bash to see where's the PHP binary.

Comment: So you don't have PHP properly installed. Or at least, properly set to be used as CLI.

Comment: This may help: http://php.net/manual/it/install.windows.commandline.php